# Broadleaf Commerce and Multiple product types

Tags: spring, hibernate, e-commerce, broadleaf-commerce

I have less than 5 Product types, and i have been following the manual at:
            http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/current/Extending-Entities-Tutorial.html 
up until "Single table inheritance", since i only have a fewer variations, i dont want to use Single table inheritance.
**I have done the following, however after rebuild and restart i dont see any tables created in the database. any ideas?**

**Books**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SB_BOOKS")
public class BookImpl extends ProductImpl implements Books {
.....
}
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<class>com.xproject.core.catalog.domain.BookImpl</class>
```

**context-entity.xml**

```
<bean id="com.xproject.core.catalog.domain.Book" class="com.xproject.core.catalog.domain.BookImpl" scope="prototype"/>
```

**UPDATE:** Please note that Table does get created if i override (extend) the BLC ProductImpl bean like this

```
<bean id="org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductImpl" class="com.xproject.core.catalog.domain.BookImpl" scope="prototype"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by following phillips hints into the BLC Code, and adding the Inheritance annotation and strategy (JOINED).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SB_BOOKS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) /* FIX */
public class BookImpl extends ProductImpl implements Books {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your blPU.hibernate.hbm2.ddl.auto set to in 'development.properties'? If you want Hibernate to automatically create tables for you then you should have this set to 'create' or 'create-drop'.  Also note that by default, the 2 applications (site and admin) have different values for this. The admin is set to 'update' while the site is set to 'create-drop'.  If you were to only start up the admin, because the Hibernate DDL is set to 'update', I do not believe that your new table would be created.

I also assume that you have created this domain in the 'core' project which is also recommended.

Source: being a Broadleaf engineer :)

Comment: Hi Phillip, thanks for the update! the domain is under the 'Core' project and i have not changed 'blPU.hibernate.hbm2.ddl.auto' from its default state which is same as you described above. please note i have had success when i subclassed the SkuImpl with a few added properties in CustomSkuImpl.java, which surprisingly worked fine, i could see the new Table created fine, the only difference i see between doing that and the above is that this time i have not overwritten a existing BLC entity (e.g. sku), by setting it again in the context-entity but created a brand new bean prototype.

Comment: Ah; I was a little confused since you had it extending from Product (which I assumed to be ProductImpl; probably just a typo) that you were extending something from Broadleaf.  In your case though, this is an entirely new entity.

If you are creating a brand new entity, the second part (modifying appcontext-entity) is not required.

Creating a new entity should be pretty trivial, looks like everything that you have done is right. Perhaps you did not re-install the 'core' project and just reinstalled 'site'?

Comment: One other comment here; every entity needs an @Id field; Hibernate might not create the table if it doesn't have a primary key. The ProductOptionImpl entity has the simplest example of this that you could copy.

Comment: Hi Phillip, thanks again for quick reply! sorry your right that was indeed a typo, i have updated the description, i am extending the ProductImpl and it seems to create the database only if i override the BLC ProductImpl in the context-entity (See description above). not if i define a new bean in context-entity which is BookImpl (extends ProductImpl)

Comment: Looks like hibernate is not creating the table,